# Problema con array devuelto por consulta sql

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Buenas tengo un problema estaba comparando en mi DB dos tablas con este código:

```
SELECT nombre FROM ( SELECT nombre FROM control UNION ALL SELECT nombre FROM becados ) t GROUP BY nombre HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Pero al llamarlo en php lo obtiene con un array:

[![salida del array][1]][1]

Pero ese arreglo tiene otros 3 arreglos dentro.

El problema en si es como logra hacer para que esos 3 arreglos les pueda realizar un **count** para poder obtener un entero de salida.

Les dejó el código:

```
session_start();
$name= $_SESSION['user'];
include("../../../base/conexion.php");
$db = new Conexion();
$query_a =mysqli_query($db,"SELECT nombre FROM ( SELECT nombre FROM control UNION ALL SELECT nombre FROM becados ) t GROUP BY nombre HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");
$control=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_a);
while ($conect_a=mysqli_fetch_array($query_a)) {
    var_dump($conect_a);
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Con ese `count` a los 3 arreglos esperas obtener el número de filas que devuelve la consulta u otro resultado distinto?

Comment: No pongas imágenes del código, copia el texto y pégalo.

Comment: @Ferni si espero obtener la cantidad de filas pero el dato que obtengo del arreglo es un string

Comment: Y... ¿por qué has escrito la consulta así de complicada? ¿Cuál es la estructura de tus tablas, cómo se relacionan entre sí y qué es lo que quieres obtener exactamente?

Comment: Con esa consulta estaba haciendo una comparación de dos tablas mediante un string, en si lo que estoy obteniendo son varios string de los arreglos lo que ocupo es obtener es un entero con referencia ala cantidad de arreglos que me tire la consulta....@A.Cedano